# Open audio segmentation datasets?

Tags: music, audio

Does anyone know of any datasets with annotated audio for audio segmentation, e.g., with speech and music?

I know of Albayzin, but these datasets seems to be restricted to research. CMMSD seems to be for just monophonic music.